# How to include a scroll bar in latex beamer presentation?

Tags: beamer

How can we create a scroll bar in LaTeX beamer presentation for content that is greater than the slide, such as code listing ?
My c-language university professor uses this in his course presentation but I do not achieve to reproduce this behaviour.

It seems to split the frame in several slides with different scroll bar states.
See following picture as an example :

[image: A slide with a scroll bar (1/2)]

[image: A slide with a scroll bar (2/2)]

Comment: Probably related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/309309/134144

Comment: Interesting. Do you know which file format he uses? PDF does not provide this feature.

Comment: @AlexG He uses .pdf.

Comment: So, it is not an interactive slider he uses while presenting. Rather, it is kind of screenshots he distributes over several `beamer` overlays. If you want interactive scrolling (based on `animate`), follow the link in @leandriis comment.

Comment: Yes indeed, but I wonder if there is a command that generate these beamer overlays automatically... Is there ?

Comment: I could neither reproduce code from leandris link, the button seems not to respond...

Comment: You need Acrobat Reader, sorry. In Okular, `animate` has basic support, but those `\mediabuttons` don't work.